# Math script font in Microsoft Office

Tags: microsoft-office, latex

I'd like to use Microsoft Office to include an equation with a math script font. In LaTex I would use, for example, the command `$\mathscr{T}$`. What's the best way to do the equivalent in Microsoft Office?

In effect I want a font that looks like the font produced when I use the \mathscr command - something like this.

[image]

Comment: You get a font that looks like that and use it as a style? Alternatively there is a tool meant to be used to display formulas within Word, it might already support such a font.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one can't import packages in Office. The workaround I've found is to use the [Formal Script font](https://www.1001fonts.com/formal-script-font.html) (the font that mathsfs mathscr uses) to put the letters in instead. Of course this does lead to clumsier looking equations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).